# how to split the original data in training, validation and testing?

Tags: machine-learning

I have the original data but i didn't know how to split the data and how to implement that data into some algorithms. can you guys help me out in this problem.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start with some tutorials to understand the cycle of a data project- there are normally several stages, like preparing and cleaning the data, etc...
There are many free resources and courses in coursera for example that you can find by searching for "data science" or "machine learning"
Regarding your specific question, I think a good place to start might be here https://www.kaggle.com/learn/intro-to-machine-learning
An example of splitting and validating can be found in section 4